# How to use ajax to save re-ordered node in Drupal 7?

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, drupal-7

I use the Jquery .sortable() function to let the site admin re-order some list elements on the start page on a Drupal 7 site. Then I want the admin to be able to save the node to keep this new sort order. In order to do this I added a Save button with js on the client side. When clicked on I have this so far:

```
            $('a.save').on('click', function () {
                // get the current nid
                var nid = Drupal.settings.mymodule.currentNid;
                var data = [];
            // copy the re-ordered html list
            data['body'] = $('.field-name-body').clone()    
                $.ajax({
                    // after reading the ajax api documentation I am more than confused about the url to use
                    url: '??',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: {
                        nid: nid,
                    body: data['body'].html()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == false) {
                        alert('Not saved, access denied.');
                    } else {
                        alert('Changes saved');
                    }
                }
            });
```

So in the normal world I would write a php script that saves the data in the node with the specified node id. And the url should point to that script... But I am stuck in the Drupal 7 documentation on how to do this... All examples i can find describes how to pull html from the server side to the client side, but I want to copy html from the client side and save it in the specfied node on the server side. Should I write a function to recieve the ajax request in a custom module? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

PARTIALLY SOLVED:
I finally found the solution about the url which became like this:

```
url: Drupal.settings.mymodule.ajaxUrl + "/" + nid,
```

I have now written a custom module where I successfully can save content in a certain node field with this code:

```
 function save_node_init() {
   drupal_add_js(array('save_node' => array('ajaxUrl' => url('save_node/ajax'))), 'setting');
   drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'save_node') . '/save_node.js');
}


function save_nod_menu() {
   $items['save_node/ajax/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'save_node_ajax_callback',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
   );

   return $items;
}


function save_node_ajax_callback() {

    $html = isset($_POST['body']) ? $_POST['body'] : null;
    $nid = isset($_POST['nid']) ? $_POST['nid'] : null;
    $node = node_load($nid);

    $node->body['und'][0]['value'] = $html;
    node_save($node);

    //ajax_deliver($html);
    drupal_exit();

}
```

As you can see I put the html in the body of the node and then saves it. My final problem is now that I don't want to replace the whole content in the body field. Just the ul and its list elements. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!